# Use multiple cores with creating mongodb indexes

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing

I want to use multiple core of my system to speed up the mongodb create index process similar to what we can do in solr or any other search engines ... something like 
`mongodb <db_name> <collection_name> ensure_index -k 4`

Is it even possible?

Comment: What makes you think it only uses a single core?

Comment: @I3arnon: Actually the process is really slow and the cpu usage is near to 100 only. Its already more than half an hour and is still going.

Comment: If it's reaching 100% then it's using up all your cores...

Comment: @I3arnon: depends of the view you choose in your host. Some hosts show 100% for one core user over 4 and some other hosts show 25%. For example, it depends on your options in `top` for Linux.

Comment: @I3arnon: by near 100% I meant it is fluctuating from 75% to 125%, and my system is quad core and I have seen it reaching to more than 300%, as seen while using default `top` command in linux

Comment: @ashish I guess that's just because the work is mostly IO bound and it doesn't use that much CPU. But I can't say for sure.

Comment: @i3arnon I can confirm its not using all cores, rather the indexing is IO bound task. its CPU bound precisely. still indexing not utilizing all cores, mongodump does utilize all cores while its IO bound rather than CPU.

Comment: It's just a theory but this might be like tar uncompression limitation, tar can't use multicore due to parallelism limitation. I think this apply for indexing, still not a big hurdle.